# How do I have a TabLayout change the content of two separate ViewPagers (which consists of fragments)?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager

First of all, I'm not too sure that my usage of two ViewPagers and a TabLayout is correct. If you have a better way, please let me know!

I currently have a TabLayout sandwiched between the two ViewPagers. I want to be able to click on the fragment titles on the TabLayout, then have the top and bottom ViewPager change based on the selected fragment title. Currently, I only have one of the ViewPagers linked with the TabLayout, but I can't figure out how to link the other ViewPager.

Just as an example, say I have frg 1, frg 2, frg 3, frg 4, frg 5, frg 6.
I click on "Tab 1" on the TabLayout --> frg 1 is shown on the top ViewPager, frg 2 is shown on the bottom ViewPager.
I click on "Tab 2" on the TabLayout --> frg 3 is shown on the top ViewPager, frg 4 is shown on the bottom ViewPager.
I click on "Tab 3" on the TabLayout --> frg 5 is shown on the top ViewPager, frg 6 is shown on the bottom ViewPager.

My FragmentPagerAdapter:
I'm not too sure if I should have two ArrayLists of fragments or just use one.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>(); // this line can cause crashes
    private final List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<Fragment> fragmentList2 = new ArrayList<>(); //not being used right now

    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titleList.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public void AddFragment (Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment); // this line can cause crashes
        titleList.add(title);
    }

    public void ClearFragments () {
        fragmentList.clear();
        titleList.clear();
    }

}
```

My MainActivity:
Currently only puts stuff in the bottom ViewPager.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    private ArrayList<BloodSugar> listBloodSugar;
    private ArrayList<Excercise> listExercise;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SelectionActivity.lastActivity = MainActivity.class;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_id);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new FragmentSymptom(), "Symptoms"); //basically frg 2 in example
        viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new FragmentBloodSugar(), "Blood Sugar"); //basically frg 4 in example
        viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new FragmentExercise(), "Exercise"); //basically frg 6 in example

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
   }
}
```

My MainActivity xml file:
I'm attempting to have the top ViewPager vertically wrap content, the TabLayout vertically wrap content, and have the bottom ViewPager take up the remaining vertical space. However, I don't know how it will actually look like as my top ViewPager doesn't have anything inside.

```
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_relative_layout">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_id2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorButtonBlue"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout_id">
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please let me know if there's anything else you need. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`viewPagerAdapter.addFragment()` is an anti-pattern because it will inevitably cause crashes after process death in production.

The correct way to implement a regular FragmentPagerAdapter is:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0) return new RulesFragment();
        if(position == 1) return new TreeFragment();
        if(position == 2) return new PredictionFragment();

        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position == 0) return "TREE RULES";
        if(position == 1) return "REGRESSION TREE";
        if(position == 2) return "PREDICTION";
      
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
    }
}
```

To get a reference to a Fragment created by a ViewPager, use the following `findFragmentByTag` scheme:

```
Fragment fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + viewPager.getId() + ":" + fragmentPosition)
```

If you need a dynamic FragmentPagerAdapter (which you do, according to your `clear()` method), then you can do:

```
public class DynamicFragmentPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "DynamicFragmentPagerAdapter";
  
    private final FragmentManager fragmentManager;
  
    public static abstract class FragmentIdentifier implements Parcelable {
        private final String fragmentTag;
        private final Bundle args;
      
        public FragmentIdentifier(@NonNull String fragmentTag, @Nullable Bundle args) {
            this.fragmentTag = fragmentTag;
            this.args = args;
        }
      
        protected FragmentIdentifier(Parcel in) {
            fragmentTag = in.readString();
            args = in.readBundle(getClass().getClassLoader());
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(fragmentTag);
            dest.writeBundle(args);
        }
      
        protected final Fragment newFragment() {
            Fragment fragment = createFragment();
            Bundle oldArgs = fragment.getArguments();
            Bundle newArgs = new Bundle();
            if(oldArgs != null) {
                newArgs.putAll(oldArgs);
            }
            if(args != null) {
                newArgs.putAll(args);
            }
            fragment.setArguments(newArgs);
            return fragment;
        }

        protected abstract Fragment createFragment();
    }
  
    private ArrayList<FragmentIdentifier> fragmentIdentifiers = new ArrayList<>();

    private FragmentTransaction currentTransaction = null;

    private Fragment currentPrimaryItem = null;

    public DynamicFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    private int findIndexIfAdded(FragmentIdentifier fragmentIdentifier) {
        for (int i = 0, size = fragmentIdentifiers.size(); i < size; i++) {
            FragmentIdentifier identifier = fragmentIdentifiers.get(i);
            if (identifier.fragmentTag.equals(fragmentIdentifier.fragmentTag)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void addFragment(FragmentIdentifier fragmentIdentifier) {
        if (findIndexIfAdded(fragmentIdentifier) < 0) {
            fragmentIdentifiers.add(fragmentIdentifier);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void removeFragment(FragmentIdentifier fragmentIdentifier) {
        int index = findIndexIfAdded(fragmentIdentifier);
        if (index >= 0) {
            fragmentIdentifiers.remove(index);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentIdentifiers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(@NonNull ViewGroup container) {
        if (container.getId() == View.NO_ID) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager with adapter " + this
                    + " requires a view id");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ReferenceEquality")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        if (currentTransaction == null) {
            currentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
        final FragmentIdentifier fragmentIdentifier = fragmentIdentifiers.get(position);
        // Do we already have this fragment?
        final String name = fragmentIdentifier.fragmentTag;
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
        if (fragment != null) {
            currentTransaction.attach(fragment);
        } else {
            fragment = fragmentIdentifier.newFragment();
            currentTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment, fragmentIdentifier.fragmentTag);
        }
        if (fragment != currentPrimaryItem) {
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        if (currentTransaction == null) {
            currentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
        currentTransaction.detach((Fragment) object);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ReferenceEquality")
    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
        if (fragment != currentPrimaryItem) {
            if (currentPrimaryItem != null) {
                currentPrimaryItem.setMenuVisibility(false);
                currentPrimaryItem.setUserVisibleHint(false);
            }
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(true);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
            currentPrimaryItem = fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(@NonNull ViewGroup container) {
        if (currentTransaction != null) {
            currentTransaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
            currentTransaction = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return ((Fragment) object).getView() == view;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("fragmentIdentifiers", fragmentIdentifiers);
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        Bundle bundle = ((Bundle)state);
        bundle.setClassLoader(loader);
        fragmentIdentifiers = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("fragmentIdentifiers");
    }
}
```